# I need to evaluate $\iint_S xdydz + (x+y)dz dx+(x^2+2z)dxdy$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, lebesgue-integral, surface-integrals

My problem asks me to evaluate the integral (using direct integration)
$$\iint_S (x)dy\wedge dz + (x+y)dz\wedge dx+(x^2+2z)dx\wedge dy$$
Being $S$ the surface of the solid limited by the following surfaces:
$$S_1=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}:2x^2+y^2=4z\},$$
$$S_2=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}:x^2+2z=2\}.$$
I've first defined parameterizations for $S_1$ and $S_2$ (I'll call them $T$ for top and $B$ for bottom):
$$T=(x,y,1-\frac{x^2}{2})$$
$$B=(x,y,\frac{2x^2+y^2}{4})$$
Being the region of integration $D:x^2+\frac{y^2}{4}\leq 1$ (ellipse).

I think (I'm not sure, correct me if I'm wrong) that:
$$\iint_S (x)dy\wedge dz + (x+y)dz\wedge dx+(x^2+2z)dx\wedge dy=\iint_S (x)dydz + (x+y)dzdx+(x^2+2z)dxdy$$
And now integrate separately for $T$ and $B$ (being $\omega=(x)dydz + (x+y)dzdx+(x^2+2z)dxdy$):
$$\iint_S \omega =\iint_T \omega - \iint_B \omega.$$
I'm stucked here, I don't know how to calculate this kind of integrals, and also I'm not sure if my work till here is correct. I think the result must gave $4\pi$. I will thank any help.

Comment: I am not familiar with the $\wedge$ notation, but your surfaces appear to be parametrized correctly (both of them are graphical, hence the parametrizations by $z = f(x, y)$ are appropriate). I trust that your region of integration is also correct; however, I have not verified that for myself. Ultimately, if your interpretation of $\wedge$ is correct, then I believe you are correct. (I imagine the negative coefficient on $\iint_B \omega \, dS$ is to account for the orientation of the normal vector.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a hint, you may pullback the form using a parametrization then integrate over a simpler domain.

$x=rsin(\theta)$, $y=2rcos(\theta)$, $D = \{ (r,\theta ): 0\leq r \leq 1$ and $-\pi \leq \theta \leq \pi$}.

$\phi (r, \theta)= (rsin\theta,2rcos(\theta), 1-r^2sin(\theta)/2)$

$\pm \iint_D \phi^{*}\omega  = \iint_T \omega$

Sign depending on the orientation. A relevant definition is

Let $\omega$ be a $k$ -form on $\mathbf{R}^{n}$ and let $S=\phi(U)$ be an oriented $k$ -dimensional geometric set parameterized by a smooth, regular parameterization
$\phi: U \rightarrow \mathbf{R}^{n},$ where $U \subset \mathbf{R}^{k}$ is a domain. Let $D \subset U$ be a region of integration. Then the integral of $\omega$ over $R=\phi(D)$ is defined to be
$$
\int_{R} \omega=\pm \int_{D} \phi^{*} \omega
$$
where the sign is positive or negative according to whether the given orientation on $S$ agrees with or does not agree with the orientation on $S$ induced by $\phi$.

You may refer to [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj5lNjW0I7qAhWQGBQKHS2MAEgQFjABegQIARAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.ucla.edu%2F%7Etao%2Fpreprints%2Fforms.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2Z3W4CacI3nbqeWJu9TmjN) document.